# Swift: App is crashing when get firedate from notification

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have registered the notification:

> application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound|UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))

In function didReceiveLocalNotification, app is crashing when i get date object from notification.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    var date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(notification.fireDate!) //app is crashing here.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RefreshVerseNotify", object: nil,userInfo:["date":date])
}
```

Following are crash log:

> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010008268c Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed:0   verse                               0x000000010008268c
>   @objc verse.AppDelegate.application
>   (verse.AppDelegate)(ObjectiveC.UIApplication,
>   didReceiveLocalNotification : ObjectiveC.UILocalNotification) -> ()
>   (AppDelegate.swift:67)

I am not getting why its crashing. Please help me...

Comment: Please explain why you tag this question with `objective-c`

Comment: I have removed objective-c

Answer (score 0):

I think `fireDate` is more used in the creation of a notification so that it knows when it should trigger.  You should note that it's optional for a reason, and setting `nil` either way is completely valid so should be accounted for.  If we're receiving a notification, I think it's relatively safe to assume that we're receiving it at its fire date, or at least close to it. Since you only care about month, day, and year, just use `NSDate()`

```
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RefreshVerseNotify", object: nil,userInfo:["date":dateString])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. I have solved it by using userinfo. I set value in userinfo and get it from userinfo

```
let date = notification.userInfo!["fdate"]as! String
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RefreshVerseNotify", object: nil,userInfo:["date":date])
```